# Ошибка при создании констатного объекта

Tags: c++

Делаю примеры из книжки С. Мейерса "Effective C++". Правило 25.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void f( int x ) 
{
    std::cout << "f( int x )" << std::endl;
}

void f( std::string* p ) 
{
    std::cout << "f( std::string* p )" << std::endl;
}

class NullClass
{
public:
    template<class T>
    operator T*() const { return 0; }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const NullClass null;
    f( null );
    return 0;
}
```

Почему у меня выдаётся ошибка при компиляции:

```
NullClass.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
NullClass.cpp:23: error: uninitialized const ‘null’
```

если убрать const, то всё норм. Почему я не могу создать константный объект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что константы должны быть инициализированы:

```
const NullClass null = NullClass();
```

Comment: спасибо, туплю ночью